# Import Spydroid ip camera project

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to import a project Spydroid ip camera master https://github.com/fyhertz/spydroid-ipcamera to Android Studio. It compiles successfully and runs on emulator with api 22 and higher, but not with api 16. In this case I get error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.dex.DexException: 
Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/NavUtils$NavUtilsImpl;
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.majorkernelpanic.spydroid"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/acra-4.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/sc-light-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/scpkix-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/scprov-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem about multidex. After adding that library your method count has reached 64k above. Just try to enable mutidex. follow this official link [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working for me. I read this and I did this change, but I get the other erroro:Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout$AccessibilityDelegate.class